# What is in a preprocessed source file that could be used to reproduce a customer issue?

Tags: preprocessor

Why would you want to collect a preprocessed source file to reproduce a customer issue?

I am thinking there is something in the preprocessed source file that could be useful to be able to identify the problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask].  I think you'll need to edit your question to be more specific.  What type of application?  What type of data file?  I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but for development it's often necessary to have a recipe or set of steps  to trigger an error before you can fix it.

Comment: It is more of a generic question. As a tech support, what are some of the things in the preprocessed file that could help us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: "It depends."  What data will help track down an error is going to be specific to each application.  The most I can say is "something that will trigger the error," kind of like [mcve] for Stack Overflow questions.